# Does Royal Air Maroc still have any unusual discounts?

Tags: air-travel, budget, morocco, royal-air-maroc

A couple Morocco guidebooks from 10-15 years ago (saying this makes me feel very old) describe unconventional discounts on Royal Air Maroc:

> You can usually get a reduced fare if
>   you buy three days in advance

-- *The Rough Guide to Morocco* (8. ed, 2007, p. 38)

> [There] is a 25 per cent discount if you are a student or under 26.

-- *Cadogan Guide: Marrakesh, Fez, Rabat* (2001, p. 12)

> Youth or student cards can sometimes... be used when booking domestic flights with the national air carrier, Royal Air Maroc, which offers up to 60% discounts.

-- *Frommer's Morocco* ([online version](http://www.frommers.com/destinations/morocco/642780#ixzz4FwWr28e9))

Do these discounts still exist? Looking at Google Flights doesn't seem to show cheaper prices three days in advance, but I know special fares don't always show up in airfare search engines. Does Royal Air Maroc have any other unconventional discounts in the vein of the ones above?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Air_Maroc#2000-present these sections in Wikipedia would make me think not.

Comment: Student and youth fares tend to be visible only on web sites catering to them specifically. I've had success at studentuniverse.com; there are others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gosh if 10 year old guidebooks make you feel old, I must be ancient.

Yes airlines still have similar fares available, such as youth fares, advance purchase fares, bereavement fares, etc.

Fares that require advance purchase are usually just listed along with other fares, no special notation.  You have to read the fare rules to see if they require "advance purchase".

Other fares like child fares or bereavement fares, you usually need to call the airline direct to avail yourself to these, they rarely appear in online options (though some online systems do allow you to enter a child's age).

It mostly just a different approach to marketing today, that focuses on the cost and not the rules.

Comment: +1, although an ideal answer would say whether Royal Air Maroc specifically still offers such discounts. Absent more information, I'll ask a bricks-and-mortar travel agent once I'm in the country.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that 2 or 3 years ago, Royal Air Maroc had a special deal for open-jaw fares, like this: X-Mohammed V-Y, where Mohammed V is the main international airport in Casablanca, and X and Y had to be two European cities from different countries (these fares were unavailable for simple round-trip tickets). I do not know if they still offer them.